# Read current and previous line of a file

Tags: perl, if-statement, file-io

This is the file i want to read:

```
N95480 G1 X143.61 Y40.23 Z0.00
N95490 G1 X142.90 Y40.06 Z0.00
N95500 G00 Z2
N95520 G00 Z2
N120 G00 Z2
N250 G00 Z2
N550 G00 Z2
N950 G00 Z2
N1440 G00 Z2
N1980 G00 Z2
N2100 G1 X81.78 Y154.21 Z-0.01
N2550 G00 Z2
N2980 G1 X79.91 Y149.90 Z-0.01
```

i have this perl code:

```
$previousLine = "";
open (MYFILE, '>testdata.txt');
    while ($continue) {
        # read file content
        open(FILE, 'readfile.txt') or die "Can't read file 'filename' [$!]\n";  
        while (<FILE>) {
            $currentLine = $_;
            if ($previousLine =~ /G00 Z/ && $currentLine =~ /G00 Z/) {
                $currentLine = "";
            }
            print MYFILE $currentLine; 
            $previousLine = $currentLine;
            $currentLine = "";

        }
        close (FILE);
    }
close (MYFILE);
```

Now the problem is this if statement:

```
if ($previousLine =~ /G00 Z/ && $currentLine =~ /G00 Z/) {
    $currentLine = "";
}
```

So basically what im trying to acheive is, if a previous line and current line has the string "G00 Z" in it, i want to change the currentLine variable to = "".
I have tried separately set ifs for previousLine and it goes into the loop. Then i tried to do separately the currentLine if and it went also into the loop but when statement if as i have, it does not work and not also when the ifs are in each other like this:

```
if ($prev...) {
    if ($current..) {
        do stuff..
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use the three-arg version of `open`.  `open (my $fh, '<', '/path/to/file');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just skip the print like:

```
open my $MYFILE, '>', 'testdata.txt' or die $!;
open my $FILE, '<', 'readfile.txt'   or die "Can't read file 'filename' [$!]\n";  
my $previousLine = "";
while (<$FILE>) {
    next if $previousLine =~ /G00 Z/ && /G00 Z/;
    print $MYFILE $_; 
    $previousLine = $_;
}
close $FILE;
close $MYFILE;
```

Comment: Thanks. This was a killer to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this right, you want to blank out lines where `G00 Z` over multiple lines? As written now, you're deleting your "previous" line every time you do find a dupe, so you end up jumping between "dupe" and "not dupe", even though they should all be dupes.

You probably want:

```
$currentLine = $_;
if ($previousLine =~ /G00 Z/ && $currentLine =~ /G00 Z/) {
   print MYFILE "";
} else {
   print MYFILE $currentLine;
}
$previousLine = $currentLine;
```

In other words, move the print statements INSIDE the `if()`, and output blank lines/current line as appropriate.

This way you print out empty lines when you do fine "Dupes", and still maintain the REAL "previous" line, instead of overwriting it with fake empty lines.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. Yes i saw now that i actually just "delete" every second duplicate, thus leaving other duplicates in the file. I will try out this.